# PDO: Why does this cause an error?

Tags: php, pdo

I dont understand why appear this error when create a object like this:

The error is in index.php in this line:

```
$dbPerfiles = new DB_Functions();
```

And the error is this:

```
PDO Connection error: invalid data source name
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
define ("DB_USER","root");
define ("DB_PASS","root");
define ("DNS","mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example");
?>
```

**DB_Connect.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
class DB_Connect {
    private static $_instance;

    //Connecting to database
    public function &pdo_connect() {    
        if(!self::$_instance) {
            try{
                self::$_instance = new PDO(DNS,DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                self::$_instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
                self::$_instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                die("PDO Connection error: ".$ex->getMessage()."<br/>");
            }
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    private function __construct() {
    }

    private function __clone() {
    }
}
?>
```

**DB_Functions.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';

    class DB_Functions extends DB_Connect{

        private $dbConnect = "";

        public function __construct() {
            $this->dbConnect = $this->pdo_connect();
        }

        public function __destruct() {
            $this->dbConnect = null;
        }

        public function getDetails() {
            try {
                //sql statement

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$max_time = 1800;
$current = time();
if(!isset($_SESSION['clientmac']['un']) ) { 
    $_SESSION['clientmac']['un'] == "";
    header('Location: index.php');
} else {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['timeLogin'])){
        $_SESSION['clientmac']['tl'] = time();
    } else {
        $session_life = $current - $_SESSION['clientmac']['tl'];    

        if ($session_life > $max_time) {
            header('Location: include/logout.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['clientmac']['tl'] = time();
        }
    }

    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $dbPerfiles = new DB_Functions();  //With this line shows the error

    //code to connect to getDetails() function in DB_Functions.php and
    //retrieve some data.

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<!--
CODE HTML
-->
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

I want connect to DB_Functions and connect with getDetails() function or other function
in this file and retrieve data.. only that!

I hope I have explained.

Regards!!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Which is written in the title:PDO Connection error: invalid data source name

Comment: Why have you got a `DNS` as an argument to your PDO constructor?

Comment: @SoldierCorp oh! sorry. Now is more clear! ;)

Comment: @arxanas It's a misspelling of the **data source name**, the DSN, the connection string that looks like `mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_database`.

Comment: On the subject, what is the value of the `DSN` constant you passed as an argument to the PDO constructor?

Comment: @MihaiStancu I just added the lines of config.php check the edited post please!!

Comment: What line does it say the error is on. That's a big tip

Comment: @ColeJohnson the only place in the code that is aware of what exactly a DSN is, is the constructor of the PDO. Otherwise any other use case the error wouldn't be the same. Also it's obvious due to the fact that it's `try`/`catch` block showing the PDO error message. The error is well pinpointed on the row that constructs the PDO object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! only I just had to add this line

```
require_once 'include/config.php';
```

above

```
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
```

and works but I dont understand why?

Because in DB_Connect.php is same this line.

Answer (score 1):

An error such as **invalid data source name** may refer to:

1. the DSN syntax being incorrect (in your case it looks correct);
2. the DSN parameters being incorrect

   1. the host may not be localhost (your mysql configuration may not allow connections via TCP or from localhost intself but i doubt it, because allowing TCP connections from localhost is the default);
   2. the database name may not be correct this (since in your code is `example`) makes me think you may not have created a database named example;

Comment: Well in dbname i put "example" only for example but my dbname is mac_system.

Comment: And respect to "localhost" .. I just put a part of code but I have many functions and works fine! But only when import or require DB_Functions in index.php, shows that error!

Comment: Well you should use a real database name for a database that actually exists. The PDO constructor tries to connect to the MySQL database which means it the database does not exist it can't connect and triggers the error.

Comment: Solved it! only I just had to add this line require_once 'include/config.php'; above require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php'; and works but I dont understand why? Because in DB_Connect.php is same line..